# How to stop draggable after drop in jQuery Pep

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery [jquery.pep.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js) plugin. I am working on [this demo](http://codepen.io/behseini/pen/bzdtg), and want to find out how I can stop `.pep` being draggable after dropping in the `.drop-target`?

```
$('.demo.droppable .pep').pep({
  droppable:   '.drop-target',
  drag: function(ev, obj){
    console.log(
      [ "There is ",
         this.activeDropRegions.length,
       " active drop region(s)." ].join('')
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `this.toggle()` inside of your `rest` callback:

```
$('.pep').pep({
  droppable: '.droppable',
  rest: function(){
   if (this.activeDropRegions.length) this.toggle();
  }
});
```

Here is a **[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/briangonzalez/pen/EJklm?editors=001)** as well.